# Changing basemap in CartoVL

Tags: basemap, carto-vl

Similar to the [provided example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-select-layer) of selecting different layers in CartoVL, is it possible to select different basemaps?

For example, my map uses:

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: carto.basemaps.voyager,
  center: [24.5,-28.6],
  zoom: 4.85,
  scrollZoom: false,
});
```

And I would like to change from the voyager to darkmatter basemap when a function is triggered using a radio button.

Comment: Check this [Change a map's style](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/setstyle/)

Comment: And this one will help as well [Create custom layer style-swap example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3979)